# Cannot open non-HTTPS webpages

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, https

Just today I got a problem with all browsers. I cannot open any websites without secured HTTP (https). This means I can open things like google, youtube, facebook, etc (and obviously StackExchange), but not something like www.amazon.com. I know I am not on a proxy, and it is not my wifi's problem as this happened connected to a different wifi as well.

My OS is Windows 10, using chrome, the error message is `err_connection_reset`

Comment: Are we supposed to guess your operating system? What is the full browser error message? Please [edit] your question to include this essential information.

Comment: My mistake. I have changed it